# Devtools chrome extension: Run script at start of every frame/page load?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a devtools Chrome extension with a dev panel. The devtools script can use [`chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.reload`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow#method-reload) to reload the page and run a script before other scripts run (in every frame in the inspected window). However, the injected script is no longer run for subsequent page reloads and newly created frames.

How can I inject a script into the inspected window that is run at the start of every subsequent page load in the inspected window?

I know I can use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) that runs at `document_start`, but that would run the script at the start of each page load regardless of whether the dev panel is open - and the script is intensive, so I'd like to avoid running the script when it's not needed.

Could the devtools script somehow listen for the beginning of page loads in the inspected window and respond by running a script in the page's context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that you can use to avoid running the script when it's not needed, as you have said, is [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi). As discussed:

> Inserting code into a page programmatically is useful when your JavaScript or CSS code shouldn't be injected into every single page that matches the pattern — for example, if you want a script to run only when the user clicks a browser action's icon.

To insert code into a page, you must have the following:

1. your extension must have **cross-origin permissions** for the page.
2. It also must be able to use the `chrome.tabs` module.

   - You can get both kinds of permission using the manifest file's permissions field.
3. Once you have permissions set up, you can inject JavaScript into a page by calling [**tabs.executeScript**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).

As also discussed in [**chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_inspectedWindow) in executing code in the inspected window, use the `tabs.executeScript` method unless you need the specific functionality that the `eval` method provides.

However in [Communicating Between Extension Components](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions), please note that:

> The DevTools page can't call `tabs.executeScript` directly. To inject a content script from the DevTools page, you must retrieve the ID of the inspected window's tab using the `inspectedWindow.tabId` property and send a message to the background page. From the background page, call `tabs.executeScript` to inject the script.

You may go through the given documentations for more information and examples.

Comment: Thanks! `tabs.executeScript` with `runAt` of `document_start ` works!